# Python requests verify certificat in production

Tags: python, django

I'm beginner in Django, python and I have an application in Django 2.2 and it communicates with vCenter REST API.
Where I have two servers
Server 1: 10.125.65.70
Server 2 : 10.126.80.80

I development I use `verify = False` But I can't use that in production.

I would like to create an if condition, which checks if we want to establish a connection with or without certificate verification.

I can't use this `verify='/path/to/public_key.pem'` because In production I use two different certificates between Vcsa(Server).

```
import requests
import os
import json
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning


requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = os.path.join("/etc/ssl/certs/")
req = requests.Session()
req.verify = False


class VmwareApi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ip = ""
        self.user = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.arg1 = ""
        self.ses = ""
        self.params = ""

    def session(self):
        try:
            a = req.post(
                "https://" + self.ip + "/api/session",
                auth=(self.user, self.password),
                timeout=1,
                verify=False,
            )
            self.ses = str(a.json())
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            return "ConnectTimeoutError"
        return req

    def param_loader(self):
        if self.params:
            self.params = json.loads(self.params)

    def vapirequestget(self):
        try:
            VmwareApi.param_loader(self)
            myreq = req.get(
                "https://" + self.ip + self.arg1,
                params=self.params,
                verify=False,
                headers={"vmware-api-session-id": self.ses},
                timeout=1,
            )
            return myreq
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            return "ConnectTimeoutError"
```

Comment: So what's the issue here? Surely you can write a function `def get_verify_value(ip)` that returns the required `verify` value for a given request?

Comment: @AKX Thanks for your answer but I don't see how to implement this.
What I wanted was just a condition if ssl active then verify the certificate else we don't verify the certificate so verify = False.

Comment: What do you mean with "if ssl active" here? If you're not using HTTPS, there's nothing to verify.